can not setTimeout with Promise
I was trying to use Promise to test different ways of using Promise then I encountered these problems.
I thought that the result will wait for 3000ms then print hello world 1 and then continuously wait for 2000ms to print hello world 2. However, after printing hello world 1, hello world 2 immediately appears.
Can any experts explain for me why this happened?


const helloWorld = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let temp = true;
    if (temp) {
      resolve("hello world 1");
    } else {
      reject("error occured");
    }
  }, 3000)
});

const helloWord2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let temp = true;
    if (temp) {
      resolve("hello world 2");
    } else {
      reject("error occured");
    }
  }, 2000)
});

helloWorld.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  helloWord2.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  })
});




Because the second timer is a shorter timeout than the first, it will already be resolved when your first .then() callback is invoked. When you do the .then() call inside that callback for the second timer, therefore, that .then() callback will run immediately because the Promise will be resolved.

What does "and then continuously wait for 2000ms" mean to you? Do you mean "and then continue to wait for 2000ms"? Because the word "continuously" can mean "repeatedly without pause", meaning it would wait 2000ms, run helloWorld2, then wait another 2000ms, etc..

The issue is that whatever function you place in you Promise triggers right away, not when it is referenced. A promise object is simply one that either store a result or a a status of 'no value yet', not a lambda that can be triggered on command. If you change your timeout functions to include a console.log, you can see the true runtime of these functions.


const helloWorld = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let temp = true;
        console.log("hello world 1");
        if(temp){
            resolve("hello world 1");
        }else {
            reject("error occured");
        }
    },3000)
});

const helloWord2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let temp = true;
        console.log("hello world 2");
        if(temp){
            resolve("hello world 2");
        }else{
            reject("error occured");
        }
    },2000)
});

helloWorld.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    helloWord2.then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    })
});



You will see the second one print out first, as it has a shorter timeout. Then the first one. You will then see your then() block execute. This block will not execute until the first Hello World timeout finishes, which by that time the second Hello World's Promise has already resolved to a value of 'hello world 2', which causes it to print immediately.
One way to resolve this issue is to store helloWorld2 as a new lambda returning the Promise, rather than as a Promise. This way, the helloWorld2 timeout will not be triggered until helloWorld1 resolves, like such:


const helloWorld = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let temp = true;
        if(temp){
            resolve("hello world 1");
        }else {
            reject("error occured");
        }
    },3000)
});

const helloWord2Lambda = () => { return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let temp = true;
        if(temp){
            resolve("hello world 2");
        }else{
            reject("error occured");
        }
    },2000)
})};

helloWorld.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    helloWord2Lambda().then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    })
});




This explains the problem very well, but how can the OP fix it?

@RoryMcCrossan that would improve the answer, but it would involve guessing what the OP really wants to do.

The second paragraph in their question seems to explain that

@RoryMcCrossan good point, thanks. I've updated.

Both helloworld and helloworld2 promises start their timers simultaneously.
In easy words to say, setTimeout inside HW is set for 3000ms and in HW2 is set for 2000ms. so HW2 resolved first and stored data "HW2" then HW resolved after 3000ms and print "HW1".
here's the catch, once helloworld promise resolves ".then" block executed, printing "hello world 1" since "helloworld2" has already resolved after 2000ms, it's result is immediately available when the ".then" block is executed.
